# Why after continue; execution further function code is executed?

Tags: php

I have a functions like:

```
public function checkItems(int $id, array $items)
{
    $this->validateItems($id, $items);

    foreach($items as $item) {
        ...// further code
    }

    return $items;
}

private function validateItems(int $id, array $items)
{
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!is_int($item->itemId)) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I write this if:

```
if (!is_int($item->itemId)) {
    continue;
}
```

inside the function checkItems() (not moved to another one) it works perfectly, because ..//further code doesn't get executed if the item is wrong. It basically returns $items if the information is not valid.

But when I move my validation into an another function, despite continue statements, at the end it loops again and the further code is executed.

Could someone tell me how to properly solve this with a validation move to another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` only works in the loop it is used in - the `foreach ($items as $item)`

if you want to use it in the validated function you either need to pass back some kind of array of valid options - or use validate in the for loop of `...// further code`

something like:

```
public function checkItems(int $id, array $items)
{
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if ($this->validateItems($id, $item) {
            ...// further code
        }
    }

    return $items;
}

private function validateItems(int $id, array $item)
{
    //$id is never used?
    if (!is_int($item->itemId)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The continue command inside loop skips any code below it inside that loop
and starts the loop from the top.

Hence putting it at the end of any loop makes no difference because there is no further code to skip.
and loop starts from the top as if there ware no continue command.

If you make validation that works this way it needs continue then this continue
will always refer to the loop it is inside.
Therefore if you move it to other function it skips execution of code below the loop
inside that function but that does not affect any other loop, especially in other function.

so if you use continue inside foreach inside checkItems()
it will skipp commands inside foreach of that function.

but if you move continue to function validateItems() and call that function
from within checkItems() then inside checkItems() will be no effect of using continue
that is inside validateItems()

to the second part how to do the validation.

Your validator should return a true/false
and inside checkItems() you test that
and if it is false then you use continue

```
<?php

public function checkItems(int $id, array $items)
{
    $this->validateItems($id, $items);

    foreach($items as $item) {

        if(false === $this->validateItems($id, $items)) {
            continue;
        }

        ...// further code
    }

    return $items;
}

private function validateItems(int $id, array $items)
{
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!is_int($item->itemId)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```