# How to calculate the length of JSON values in php?

Tags: php, json

I have a **JSON as shown below** in which I want to calculate through php how many values are present inside `posts_id_en`. At present, it is 7 as shown below:

```
{
    "posts_id_en": "149968, 149939, 149883, 149877, 149876, 149847, 154303",
    "posts_id_fr": "149974,149953,149926, 149920, 149901",
    "episode_status": "3"
}
```

In php code on doing `echo $data->{"posts_id_en"};`, it displays the values as shown below:

```
149968, 149939, 149883, 149877, 149876, 149847, 154303
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what php code I need to use so that we can calculate number of values entered inside `posts_id_en`. At this moment, it is entered 7 as shown above.

Comment: Regex only: [`$cnt = preg_match_all('/(?:\G(?!^)|"posts_id_en":\s*")[^",]+,?/', $str);`](https://3v4l.org/htU51) but I'd prefer the `json_decode` too :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The items you are trying to count are in a single string. First, you must break the string into items, then you can count them.

Take the json and make it into a php array

```
$jsonData = '{
    "posts_id_en": "149968, 149939, 149883, 149877, 149876, 149847, 154303",
    "posts_id_fr": "149974,149953,149926, 149920, 149901",
    "episode_status": "3"
}';
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

then split the string with the delimiter ", "

```
$items = explode(", ", $data['posts_id_en']);
```

then count

```
echo count($items);
```

Comment: There was a slight mistake in my question. I have modified my question a bit.

Comment: I have updated my answer to your new json - but it doesn't matter.

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430459/how-to-convert-mp4-files-into-mp3-on-button-click-using-ffmpeg-php). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "posts_id_en": "149968, 149939, 149883, 149877, 149876, 149847, 154303",
    "posts_id_fr": "149974,149953,149926, 149920, 149901",
    "episode_status": "3"
}';
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$post_id = $decoded['posts_id_en'];

$resultList = [];
foreach($decoded as $key => $entry) {
    $everyNumberAsArray = explode(',', $entry);    
    $count = count($everyNumberAsArray);
    $resultList[$key] = $count;
}

var_export($resultList);
```

gives output:

```
array (
  'posts_id_en' => 7,
  'posts_id_fr' => 5,
  'episode_status' => 1,
)
```

to get particular values you use them this way:

```
echo $resultList['posts_id_en'] . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
```

that gives you:

```
7
```

Comment: beat me to posting while i was working on an answer :P

Comment: @Jimmix I have updated my question. There was a slight mistake in my question.

Comment: @Alo I wasn't enough careful last time so you did [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56317379/1174405) :P

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be that we first `json_decode`, then validate numbers in our desired attribute, and count the matches:

```
$str = '{
    "posts_id_en": "149968, 149939, 149883, 149877, 149876, 149847, 154303",
    "posts_id_fr": "149974,149953,149926, 149920, 149901",
    "episode_status": "3"
}';

$str_array = json_decode($str, true);

preg_match_all('/(\d+)/s', $str_array["posts_id_en"], $matches);

echo sizeof($matches[0]);
```

#### Output

```
7
```